# What happened to Comodo Defense+?

Tags: firewall, comodo-firewall

I just updated Comodo to version 7, and there is only the Firewall now. Defense+ seems to have been discontinued as I can no longer find it. What happened to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. They simply renamed it to HIPS for whatever reason.